# Xenial with 4.4 kernel still requiring reboots

Tags: server, apt, kernel, 16.04, unattended-upgrades

I'm seeing a 16.04 system with a 4.4 kernel requiring reboots upon upgrading the kernel. I had thought that with the 4.x kernel no more reboots would be required due to the hot patching support that was integrated in a similar way to how things like ksplice would work. Does anyone know why this is still happening?

```
cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs 
linux-image-4.4.0-22-generic
linux-base
linux-base

less /var/log/apt/history.log
Start-Date: 2016-05-07  13:37:35
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-signed-image-4.4.0-22-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-22.39, automatic), linux-image-4.4.0-22-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-22.39, automatic), linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-22.39, automatic), linux-headers-4.4.0-22:amd64 (4.4.0-22.39, automatic), linux-headers-4.4.0-22-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-22.39, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.21.22, 4.4.0.22.23), linux-signed-image-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.21.22, 4.4.0.22.23), linux-signed-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.21.22, 4.4.0.22.23)
End-Date: 2016-05-07  13:38:12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canonical Live Patch was just announced today for 16.04:

- http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2016/10/canonical-livepatch.html
- https://www.ubuntu.com/server/livepatch

This uses the live patching technology in the upstream Linux kernel since 4.0 was released.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're thinking of is called kGraft. Although integrated into Linux starting with version 4, the distro has to be configured to support it; as far as I can tell, so far only SUSE Linux Enterprise is offering support for kGraft patches at this time.